# JQuery submit function working sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I'm making a web application for a class which contains a jsp file that uses jquery. I want the app to trigger an alert right before submitting. This works some of the time in my real program, and other times the alert is never triggered. I can't seem to peg down an instance where it always works or never works. My error console is silent on the matter, unless I add Firebug breakpoints. Then it gives me

```
Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
Line: 2
```

But I have no idea what that means. As far as Firebug goes, I can't understand why the evaulation stops before the alert message.

I tried to make an sscce documenting the problem, but I guess it was too different from my real program, because submit never worked. I'll show some code from my real program. (Sorry about the lack of SSCCE.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#questionDisplay").submit(function() {
        var correctAnswer = $(".correctAnswer").attr("value");
        var answer = "";

        if ($(".multipleChoice").length > 0) {
            answers = $("input:checked");
            for (var obj in answers) {
                answer += obj.attr("value") + "#";
            }
        } else if ($(".fillBlank").length > 0) {
            for (var answerNo = 1; $(".answer" + answerNo).length > 0; ++answerNo) {
                answer += $(".answer" + answerNo).attr("value") + "#";
            }
        } else {
            answer = $(".answer1").attr("value");
        }

        if (answer == correctAnswer) {
            alert("Yes! Correct!");
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, incorrect.");
        }
    });
});
```

The jsp is a huge mess (we have to use scriplets :( ), but if you'd like to see it just lemme know.

How do I get my submit handler to work every time?

Comment: There are many possibilities and see if you can create an example at jsfiddle.net. Some things you can check for include: =>Make sure the include sequence is proper, => #questionDisplay must be your form tag, you are using many classes to get attribute values and unique processing which is seemingly incorrect way.. Try to view source, remove your corporate information and try to replicate the issue at jsfiddle.net. Or, post more code here which will give insights of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `answers` is a jQuery collection of elements. Looping through it using `for(var obj in answers) { }` is actually looping through the properties of answers, not the elements themselves. Therefore, calling .attr() on a property is not going to work.

In general, if I see my debugger state that jQuery has an error, it's 99.9% of the time me calling a jQuery method on a non-jquery selected object. In this case, I saw the error in Chrome's JavaScript console, and sometimes results may vary with different consoles.

A good practice is to prefix variables that store jQuery elements with $ to indicate that they are jQuery objects. For instance, `$answers` makes it easier to keep track of what it contains.

Use:

```
answers.each(function() {
     answer += $(this).attr("value") + "#";
});
```

Instead of this:

```
for (var obj in answers) {
    answer += obj.attr("value") + "#";
}
```

Comment: Or `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Comment: I can't believe that was the entire problem. Javascript is ridiculous.

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent silly stuff like this from happening in the future?

Comment: @Derek, perhaps you'd like to explain why this seemingly-innocuous change works?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more info and tips for @Eva.