# jQuery ajaxForm complete works sometimes, other times it only fires a native javascript function then stops

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This may be a duplicate of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894532/jquery-submit-function-working-sometimes), but I must revive it as my issue seems to be a little deeper than this. I'm currently using **ajaxForm()** to submit a 4 question quiz to a PHP script, receive the result, and then populate it back into the DIV. The `beforeSend` function fires, sending the information to the `ajax.php` script. `beforeSend` also shows a loading graphic in the quiz container. Then the `complete` function fires properly as `ajax.php` returns the HTML to be populated back into the DOM. At that point, everything stops. The next line is a call to `slideUp` the loading div and then display the returned information in the quizContainer.

At this point if I put in a javascript `alert` it always fires, meaning that `complete` is at least firing when it should, but the jQuery reference to the loading div is completely ignored. Here's the code for the javascript file that handles the submission - the section handling this is "Handle the quiz submission":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Get rid of the message box after 15 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#message').slideUp('fast');
}, 10000);

// Handle the Course List LIs
$('#courseList li').on('click', function () {
    // Get the background color as it's set initially
    var color = $(this).attr('oColor');
    jQuery('div', this).toggle('slow', function () {
        if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).css('background-color', color);
        }
    });
    
    // Change the background to be the same as the content background when it's expanded
    if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#33CC66');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    }
});

// Handle the quiz submission
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
if ($('#quizForm').exists()) {
    $('#quizForm').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#quizContainer').slideUp('fast', function () {
                $('#loading').show();
            });
        },
        complete: function(xhr, theStatus) {
            alert(theStatus);
            $('#loading').slideUp('fast', function () {
                $('#quizContainer').html(xhr.responseText);
                $('#quizContainer').show();
            });
        }
    });
}

});
```

If necessary I can provide more information and a temporary login to access this if anybody would like to see it in action. I'm currently using jQuery 1.8.1(.)

Thanks for any help!
Jon

Comment: One other interesting thing to note: When I use breakpoints in Firebug, and it encounters the issue (hitting `$('#loading').slideUp()` and then ignoring it and jumping to the end of the function, if I hit Rerun, everything works as it's supposed to - the div slides up and the response is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first argument of the `complete` function is `xhr.responseText` rather than an `xhr` object which is actually the third argument. Try removing `.responseText` from your `complete:` function.

Comment: The xhr argument is returning properly as when I look at it through Firebug, xhr and then xhr.reponseText are properly populated. It's just that the function stops right when it hits `$('#loading')`. I'm currently looking to see if there is anything out there that talks about `slideUp` not functioning properly.

Comment: can you confirm by changing the alert to show you ````xhr.responseText````? just to be sure. Failing that if you think it's a bug I'd suggest updating jquery to the latest if that's a possibility.

Comment: This does fit the symptoms as referencing a variable that doesn't exist would cause js to just stop. Also remember that you are passing in a function as an argument to ````slideUp()```` so I would expect it to fail where it has.

Comment: Yeah, when I change the alert to show `xhr.responseText` it shows the html that was returned from the `ajax.php` file. Tried it multiple times to be sure, and it shows every time. :/

Comment: OK what happens if you take the ````$("#quiz-container")```` stuff out of the ````slideUp()```` complete function?

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with the callback function at the end of `slideUp()`. I went through and moved things around such that it populates the xhr.responseText first, then shows the `$('#quizContainer')`, then hides the loading graphic. Things are a little more clunky now, but at least it works and is properly displaying the user's controls. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also originally thought that it might be a bug in jQuery 1.8.1, so I changed it to 1.8.3 as well as 1.9.1, but the error still existed.